# How do you use aggregation in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a dataset like this.

101,Amitabh,20000,1
102,Shahrukh,10000,5
103,Akshay,11000,1
104,Anubhav,5000,4
105,Pawan,2500,5

How do you achieve the below statement.
 Top 5 employees with highest rating (column 4). (In case two employees have same rating, employee with name coming first in dictionary should get preference)

Answer (score 0):

First use ORDER BY with columns rating DESC and name ASC ( default is ASC).
Than use LIMIT to display top records.